# Get Apache Tika Mp3 parser

Tags: java, apache-tika

Can anybody tell me how I can get the Apache Tika Mp3 Parser? I have a Gradle application running and added the following dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '2.0.0-ALPHA'
implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '2.0.0-ALPHA', ext: 'pom'
```

The org.apache.tika.parsers package is available. 
The org.apache.tika.parsers.mp3 package is **not** available. 
Where I have to look to determine which dependency I need for .mp3 package?

Comment: Do you need to use the alpha version of Apache Tika? If not, the latest stable one is 1.26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at `2.0.0-ALPHA` version, this is completely different than `1.x` stream (with `1.26` being the latest at this time).

In `2.0.0-ALPHA`, you can find `Mp3Parser` class in [tika-parser-audiovideo-module](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parser-audiovideo-module) module. It's in the `org.apache.tika.parser.mp3` package.

For version `1.26` you should be using [tika-parsers](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers) (like you do in your question). The `Mp3Parser` class is in `org.apache.tika.parser.mp3` package, I just checked it..

btw. You should not use `ext: 'pom'` when defining the dependency for `1.26` - that's probably why you don't see that class when you use that version